# Finding video id on html website using python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping an html file, each page has a video on it, and in the html there is the video id. I want to print out the video id.

I know that if i want to print a headline from a div class i would do this

```
with open('yeehaw.html') as html_file:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

article = soup.find('div', class_='article')
headline = article.h2.a.text
print headline
```

However the id for the video is found inside a  data-id='qe67234'
I dont know how to access this 'qe67234' and print it out.

please help thank you!

Comment: Please show us the relevant part of the HTML file. Also, please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the tag for data-id begins with div:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="_article" data-id="qe67234"></div>')
results = soup.findAll("div", {"data-id" : re.compile(r".*")})
print('output: ', results[0]['data-id'])

# output: qe67234
```

Comment: data-id will be different everytime, so cant hardcode it in the code

Comment: @LordEduardo it's not harcoded. The code above finds data-id dynamically. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Dont use `re.compile(r".*")`. You can simply do `"data-id": True`.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that the data-id is in div*

BeautifulSoup.find returns you the found html element as a dictionary. You can therefore navigate it using standard means to get access to the text (as you did in your question) as well as html tags (as shown in the code below)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="_article" data-id="qe67234">')
soup.find("div", {"class":"_article"})['data-id']
```

Note that, oftentimes, video elements require JS for playback, and you might not be able to find the necessary element if it was scraped with a non-javascript client (i.e. python `requests`).

If this happens, you have to use tools like `phantomjs + selenium` browser to get the website combined with the javascript to perform your scraping.

**EDIT** 
If the `data-id` tag itself is not constant, you should look into `lxml` library to replace `BeautifulSoup` and use `xpath` values to find the element that you need

Comment: data-id will be different everytime, so cant hardcode it in the code

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, the soup (`soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="_article" data-id="qe67234">')`) will come from your browser. The second line `soup.find("div", {"class":"_article"})['data-id']` will allow you to get the data-id tag value from the <div> tag. If the `data-id` tag itself is not constant, you should look into [lxml](https://lxml.de/) library and use [xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath) values to find the element that you need